# Return a string from an assigned object in R

Tags: r, string

I have this code:

```
model_to_use  <-  m1 
model_name    <-  deparse(substitute(m1))
```

My intention is to modify this code such as:

```
model_name    <-  deparse(substitute(model_to_use))
```

***But to STILL GET,***

"m1"

How I can do that in R ?

Comment: please check again my question

Comment: Please try using attributes `attr(m1, "name") <- deparse(substitute(m1)); model_to_use  <-  m1 ; model_name    <-  attr(model_to_use, "name")`